# Most efficient method of logging data to MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging

We have a service which sees several hundred simultaneous connections throughout the day, peeking at about 2000, for about 3 million hits a day, and growing.  With each request I need to log 4 or 5 pieces of data to MySQL, we originally used the logging that came with the app were using however it was terribly inefficient and would run my db server at >3x the average cpu load, and would eventually bring the server to it knees.

At this point we are going to add our own logging to the application (php), the only option I have for logging data is the MySQL db, as this is the only common resource available to all of the http servers. This data will be mostly writes however everyday we generate reports based on the data, then crunch and archive the old data.

What recommendations can be made to ensure that I don't take down our services with logging data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution we took with this problem was to create an [archive table](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html) then regularly ( every 15 minutes, on an app server) crunch the data and put it back into the tables that were used to generate reports.  The archive table of course did not have any indices, the tables which the reports are generated from have several indices.

### Some stats on this approach:

Short Version:  >360 times faster

Long Version:

The original code/model did direct inserts into the indexed table, and the average insert took .036 seconds, using the new code/model inserts took less than .0001 seconds (I was not able to get an accurate fix on the insert time I had to measure 100,000 inserts and average for the insert time).  The post-processing (crunch) took an average 12 seconds for several tens-of-thousands records.  Overall we were greatly pleased with this approach and so far it has worked incredibly well for us.

Comment: I'd love to know, how did you deal with cleaning up the log data from the archive table? archive does not support deletes...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, I recommend you try to leverage the fact that you don't need to read this data immediately and pursue a "periodic bulk commit route".  That is, buffer the logging data in RAM on the app servers and doing periodic bulk commits.  If you have multiple application nodes, some sort of randomized approach would help even more (e.g., commit updated info every 5 +/- 2 minutes).

The main drawback with this approach is that if an app server fails, you lose the buffered data.  However, that's only bad if (a) you absolutely need all of the data and (b) your app servers crash regularly.  Small chance that both are true, but in the event they are, you can simply persist your buffer to local disk (temporarily) on an app server if that's really a concern.

The main idea is:

- buffering the data
- periodic bulk commits (leveraging some sort of randomization in a distributed system would help)

Another approach is to stop opening and closing connections if possible (e.g., keep longer lived connections open).  While that's likely a good first step, it may require a fair amount of work on your part on a part of the system that you may not have control over.  But if you do, it's worth exploring.